# Django template renders all my files at once

Tags: python, django

I am stuck with this issues for a while now. It goes like this: I have a model with lectures. I want that for every lecture to be able to upload multiple files, so I created a model that has FileField. So in my template, I want that for every lecture, the files would be displayed and downloadable as well. The Issue is that every lecture displays all the files that have ever been uploaded in the admin panel. Here is my code:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
    lecture_category = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, "Classes "),
                                                    (1, "Seminars"),
                                                    ), default=0)
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    files = models.OneToOneField('FileUpload', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lecture_category)


class FileUpload(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.files)

    def file_link(self):
        if self.files:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.files.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'
```

```html
  <ul>
        {% regroup lectures by get_lecture_category_display as category_list %}
        <h3>Lectures</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in category_list %}
                <strong>
                    <li>{{ category.grouper }}</li>
                </strong>
                <ul>
                    {% for c in category.list %}
                        .............
                        <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                        <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                        {% for file in files %}
                            {% if file.files %}
                            <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.files.url }}'>download</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

```python
def courses(request, slug):
    query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
               'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
               'files': FileUpload.objects.all(),
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

Here is the current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxC6K.png

Answer (score 2):

Stop fetching the files as a separate queryset:

```
def courses(request, slug):
    query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
               'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

You can then follow the one-to-one field from lecture to `files`.

```
{% for lecture in category.list %}
  <li>{{ lecture.lecture_title }}</li>
  <li>{{ lecture.content }}</li>
  {% if lecture.files %}
    <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ lecture.files.files.url }}'>download</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since it's a one-to-one field to a single file upload, it would make more sense to name the field `file` instead of `files`:

```
file = models.OneToOneField('FileUpload', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

You would then have to update the template to use `lecture.file` instead.

Comment: Not working.. no files are getting displayed. Btw, I named it files to make it more obvious in admin panel that u can add more.

Comment: If the `{% if lecture.files %}` isn't showing anything, then the simplest explanation is that those lectures do not have `lectures.files` set. Check in the Django admin to make sure.

Comment: Ok, I had to add new lectures for some reason. Now they show and work. One more thing tho, if I add another file, the first file will not be displayed anymore. I can only display last uploaded file per lecture.

Comment: Yes, it’s a one-to-one field, so each lecture has a single file. It might make more sense to have a foreign key on the upload file model, or a many-to-many field instead.

Comment: For foreign key I have same result. Would u like to move to a discussion ?

Comment: I was suggesting that you have `lecture = ForeignKey('Lecture', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` on the `FileUpload` model. Although this assumes that *every* file upload is linked to a lecture. If you're still stuck, it would be better to ask a new question because this is a separate issue to your template.

Comment: I did that actually and solved it. Thanks for support !